# How many sub choices...

Tags: combinatorics

How many sub choices if there are 3 types of bread, 6 different types of meat, 8 different veggies, 4 different kinds of cheese

You must choose 1 bread.
You can choose any Meats, including none.
You can choose any veggies, including none.
You must choose 1 cheese.

I am confident in finding the number of choices regarding the bread and cheese 3(4) = 12, so my question lies in the toppings

Should I find the sum of each topping combination (Example: meats = 6C0 + 6C1 + 6C2...+ 6C6) then multiply the results with the sum of the veggies with the 12 above?

[sum of meats * sum of veggies * 12]

Or, should I treat the meat and veggie as one category? So, there would be 16 choices of toppings including having none [6+8+2(no cheese and no meat)] then calculate the sum of the combinations (16C0 + 16C1 + 16C2...+ 16C16) and multiply it by the 12 above?

[sum of all toppings * 12]

Thank you for your insight. I hope I'm somewhere in the ballpark!

Comment: For each meat and each veggie, you have two choices - either you choose it or you do not.

Comment: *Possible ambiguity* : Are you allowed to choose more than one kind of meat?  Are you allowed to choose more than one kind of veggie?  Are you allowed to choose *more* than one kind of cheese?  Are you allowed to choose *more* than one kind of bread?  The last question is somewhat absurd, but it highlights how the question relates to the other (more plausible) ambiguities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your suggestion for the meat options, "6C0 + 6C1 + 6C2...+ 6C6", is correct but there is an easier way to formulate it. You are either choosing or not choosing each of the meat varieties, giving $2$ options per variety and thus $2^6$ options in the meat section.

That can be seen as a reason "why" the combinatoric identity holds:

$$ \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom nk = 2^n $$

Comment: This makes sense, Thank you. I do have a question though. What about the option to not have meat? would it not be 2^7. as in first, I have to choose to have meat or not, then I choose to have each variety or not? making it seven options, not six? or am I missing something?   Hugh thanks btw!

Comment: Not having meat is covered here by saying "no" to each of the six options.

Comment: So simple, my overthinking mind missed it..lol. thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can group them together, but in this case you can directly choose a subset of the set of 8 + 6 = 14 (meats + veggies).

That gives finally $12.2^{14}$